# htaccess for subdomain no longer in use

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, migration, subdirectory

I had a subdomain https://sub.rootdir.com/  which was migrated to the root domain and to a new host.
I want to redirect this subdomain to the root folder. The host told me to re-create the subdomain and then create an '.htaccess' file in which you can set redirection rules such as:
Redirect 301 / https://rootdir.com/

I have kind of no idea what to type in the htaccess file.
Can I please get help from you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file in your subdomain folder and enter this code in;

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^rootdir\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) https://rootdir.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out from other posts here tx

```html
#mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.rootdir.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.rootdir.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```